# JQuery TextNTags plugin removes tag formatting after changing the trigger `syntax`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am using [JQuery TextNTags plugin](http://daniel-zahariev.github.io/jquery-textntags/) in my web application. This is original code:

```
$.browser = {
    webkit: true
};
$(function () {
    $('textarea.tagged_text').textntags({
        triggers: {'!': {
            uniqueTags   : false,
            syntax       : _.template('![<%= id %>:<%= type %>:<%= title %>]'),
            parser       : /(!)\[(\d+):([\w\s\.\-]+):([\w\s@\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]+)\]/gi,
            parserGroups : {id: 2, type: 3, title: 4},
        }, '#': {
            uniqueTags   : false,
            syntax       : _.template('#[<%= id %>:<%= type %>:<%= title %>]'),
            parser       : /(#)\[(\d+):([\w\s\.\-]+):([\w\s@\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]+)\]/gi,
            parserGroups : {id: 2, type: 3, title: 4},
        }, 'PP:': {
            uniqueTags   : false,
            syntax       : _.template('PP:[<%= id %>:<%= type %>:<%= title %>]'),
            parser       : /(PP:)\[(\d+):([\w\s\.\-]+):([\w\s@\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]+)\]/gi,
            parserGroups : {id: 2, type: 3, title: 4},
        }},
        onDataRequest:function (mode, query, triggerChar, callback) {
            var data = {
                '!': [
                    { id:1, name:'Daniel Zahariev (via !)',   'img':'http://example.com/img1.jpg', 'type':'contact1' },
                    { id:2, name:'Daniel Radcliffe (via !)',  'img':'http://example.com/img2.jpg', 'type':'contact1' },
                    { id:3, name:'Daniel Nathans (via !)',    'img':'http://example.com/img3.jpg', 'type':'contact1' }
                ],
                '#': [
                    { id:4, name:'Daniel Zahariev (via #)',  'img':'http://example.com/img1.jpg', 'type':'contact2' },
                    { id:5, name:'Daniel Radcliffe (via #)', 'img':'http://example.com/img2.jpg', 'type':'contact2' },
                    { id:6, name:'Daniel Nathans (via #)',   'img':'http://example.com/img3.jpg', 'type':'contact2' }
                ],
                'PP:': [
                    { id:7, name:'Daniel Zahariev (via PP:)',  'img':'http://example.com/img1.jpg', 'type':'contact3' },
                    { id:8, name:'Daniel Radcliffe (via PP:)', 'img':'http://example.com/img2.jpg', 'type':'contact3' },
                    { id:9, name:'Daniel Nathans (via PP:)',   'img':'http://example.com/img3.jpg', 'type':'contact3' }
                ]
            };

            query = query.toLowerCase();
            var found = _.filter(data[triggerChar], function(item) { return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1; });

            callback.call(this, found);
        }
    });



    $('.get-syntax-text4').click(function() {
        $('textarea.tagged_text_ex4').textntags('val', function(text) {
            alert(text);
            console.log(text);
        });
    });
});
```

In this code I am trying to change the syntax of each trigger by removing `:<%= title %>` from it.

But when I do that it removes tag background color. Following is the fiddle before modifying syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/6205ef8j/6/ and after modifying: http://jsfiddle.net/6205ef8j/7/

Can you tell me why this is happening?

Also I have another question which I think is related to my above problem. If anyone can tell me what is the use of `parserGroups`? In the documentation it's written that:

> Object that maps the indexes of the parsed groups with the
>   corresponding tag properties.

But I am unable to understand this definition.

Answer (score 0):

The background comes from an actual separate layered div tag where the title is used to map the text with formatting. Also if you want to use the edit mode you'll need to keep the title.